# WPF custom shaped wrap panel

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, wrappanel

I have a Window with a WrapPanel containing a variable number of custom items.
[image]

By clicking on an item I need to display a panel containing some information about the item selected.
While displaying this panel I'd like the WrapPanel to fill all the available space like in the picture below.
[image]

The best I could come up with was to create a UserControl with a Grid with two row, each one containing a WrapPanel.
When the information panel is collapsed I would display only the first WrapPanel which will contains all the items.
While the information panel is visible, I would show both WrapPanels, moving some of the items from the first WrapPanel to the second.

Honestly though, I don't really like it and I was wondering if there was a better solution.

Comment: Google VariableSizedWrapGrid for WPF